# TikZ \pic gives error in a german exsheets enviroment

Tags: tikz-pgf, exsheets

I am a german math teacher and prepearing my tests with a combination of exsheets and tikz. Since I am at triangles  currently i tried to prepare a text but run into an error. I narrowed it down and created the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, quotes, babel}

\usepackage{exsheets}
    \SetupExSheets{
        question/type=exam,
        question/headings=topic,
        solution/print=false,
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{question}
Test mit Sonderzeichen äöü

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (1,0);
\coordinate (c) at (0,1);
\draw (a)--(b);
\draw (a)--(c);
\pic["$\alpha$",draw=black] {angle=b--a--c};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{question}
\end{document}
```

Getting rid of babel or exsheets solves the problem. Posting the tixzpicture outside the question environment solves it aswell. But all the solutions are not ideal, since i use mini pages to post the picture next to the exercise and question inside the mini pages doesn't show the points, the picture below the question uses more space.

Regards

Comment: Why not use of `pic text=$\alpha$`.

Comment: For what it's worth: the problem doesn't show in `exsheets`' soon to be published successor [`xsim`](https://github.com/cgnieder/xsim)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to originate from the shorthand character `"` activated by `babel`. These enable you to type e.g. `"a` to get the umlaut "ä" etc. As you also entered umlauts in your example I'm guessing you do not want to use these shorthands anyway, so you can just disable them by adding the option `shorthands=off` to the babel package.

Note that I also added `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` to get the umlauts working. This only works if your file is saved in UTF8 encoding. Depending on your editor and environment, there may be other options for the encoding, e.g. Latin-1 is common on Windows. In that case, simply change the `utf8` option accordingly, e.g. to `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`. You will probably get strange errors if the encoding is not set correctly. The only other change I made below is setting `question/headings` to `block` instead of `topic` - you have probably defined that elsewhere in your code, but it gave me an error message. The code as shown below works fine for me.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,shorthands=off]{babel} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, quotes, babel}

\usepackage{exsheets}
    \SetupExSheets{
        question/type=exam,
        question/headings=block,
        solution/print=false,
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{question}
Test mit Sonderzeichen äöü

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (1,0);
\coordinate (c) at (0,1);
\draw (a)--(b);
\draw (a)--(c);
\pic["$\alpha$",draw=black] {angle=b--a--c};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{question}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are right, I might have cut off to much information, so the minimal example gave an error because of the heading. Your solution works fine, I didn't even know, that I am able to disable the shorthands. They were the main reason i started using \enquote, because of the behavior, if there was a vocal behind. Thank you very much!